# drupal 7 form, simple check on hook_submit

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to understand drupal forms by trial and error (not getting along famously with Drupal Documentation), and I'm a bit confused as why doesn't this work:

```php
function sform() {
    $form['password'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password',
        '#title' => 'enter 1234'
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => '1234 and then click',
    );

    $form['#method'] = 'post';

    return $form;
}
function sform_submit($form_id, $form) {
    if (isset($form['values']['password']) && $form['values]']['password'] == "1234") {
        drupal_set_message(t('Success;'), '');
    }
    else {
        drupal_set_message("({$form['values']['password']})", 'warning');
        drupal_set_message(t('Failure'), 'error');
    }
}
```

I know it all extremely basic and the idea isn't for it to stay in any way like this. As I said I'm just prodding the API to see what works and how.

But the thing is, the basic check is that the "password" field exists and is equal to "1234". And it fails every time. In the failure branch I spit out what value I've got from "password", and I see that it was "1234" nonetheless...

Is there some very obvious reason why the comparison between $form['values']['password'] and "1234" shouldn't be working as I intend here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo on your if test:

```
$form['values]']['password']
//should be
$form['values']['password']
```

Also it looks like you have your functions setup incorrectly, take a look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7

You should be passing `$form` and `$form_state` (by reference) when using forms.

Taken from link above:

```
function my_module_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}
function my_module_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Validation logic.
}
function my_module_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Submission logic.
}
```

Plus your menu hook should call `drupal_get_form` as the callback and your function name as the page arguements.

```
$items['sform'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('sform'),
    'access arguments' => array('some rule'),
);
```

Comment: F*ck. I need to sleep a bit more. :( Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on that answer. You converted my silly question in a useful answer. Kudos to you.

Comment: Been in the same boat as you. I agree Drupal's documentation is sometimes quite hard to navigate and find the info you need. Figured this would help you down the right track for the future when you start doing more complex things.